# Laravel two queries, how do one query?

Tags: php, laravel

I have model post. I use this package: https://github.com/cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable

I have accesor in model post:

```
protected $appends = ['views'];

public function getViewsAttribute()
{
    return $this->views()->count();
}
```

In blade when I `foreach` my posts:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
     Views: {{ $post->views }} {{ trans_choice('trans.views', $post->views)
@endforeach
```

I get two queries with `views`. And if posts 100, then queries will be 200.. For each post I get two same queries. How I can resolve this? If I delete `{{ trans_choice('trans.views', $post->views)` Then I get one query.

Answer (score 3):

Given that `views` is a Laravel relationship, you can use [the `withCount` function to "eager load" the value](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).

```
$posts = Post::withCount('views')->get();
```

Comment: But default `appends` is not load views attribute? Why?

Comment: @Dumitru Because the attribute won't be called `views`, it'll be called `views_count`. Append that instead.